# Printing each word in a line rather than character in Python?

Tags: python

Consider the following codes and outputs

**Code1**:

```
ls = ["one is one","two is two","three is three"]
for each_item in ls:
    print(each_item)
```

**Output1:**

[image]

**Code2:**

```
ls = ["one is one","two is two","three is three"]
for each_item in ls:
    for each_word in each_item:
        print(each_word)
```

**Output2:**

[image]

My intention is to print as follows

> one
>
> is
>
> one
>
> two
>
> is
>
> two
>
> three
>
> is
>
> three

Where I need to modify to print in desired order?

Comment: use the split method on `each_item` `for each_word in each_item.split()`

Comment: Why down-voting? Is it a question of substandard?

Comment: While the question is relatively basic, it was well formulated and asked. I don't think the down votes are warranted @hanugm

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I think they are due to using images in the output instead of actual text. But nevertheless, not warranted.

Answer (score 1):

Per taoufik's comment, you want to [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) each sentence before iterating over it. This is because, by default, when you iterate over a string in Python it will go character by character. By calling `split`, you split the string (by spaces) into a list of words. See below.

```
ls = ["one is one","two is two","three is three"]

for sentence in ls:
    for word in sentence.split():
        print(word)

one
is 
one
two
is
two
three
is
three
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ls = ["one is one","two is two","three is three"]
words = []
for each_item in ls:
    words = each_item.split()
    for word in words:
        print(word)
```